# How to replace multi ordered list with select dropdown mootools?

Tags: select, replace, mootools

I have following html markup,  bit more than demo here with mixture of li/ul dropdowns and different class names for sub ul's

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="linik">Title</a></li>
  <li><a href="linik">Title</a></li>
  <li><a href="linik">Title</a></li>
  <li><a href="linik">Title</a>
    <ul class="subnav">
      <li><a href="linik">Title</a></li>
      <li><a href="linik">Title</a></li>
      <li><a href="linik">Title</a></li>
      <li><a href="linik">Title</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="linik">Title</a></li>
  <li><a href="linik">Title</a></li>
  <li><a href="linik">Title</a></li>
   <li><a href="linik">Title</a>
    <ul class="subnav">
      <li><a href="linik">Title</a></li>
      <li><a href="linik">Title</a></li>
      <li><a href="linik">Title</a></li>
      <li><a href="linik">Title</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

to accommodate mobile browsers I would like to convert ul list to select list like

```
<select class="nav" onchange="location.href=this.value">
<option  value="link">Title</option>
<option  value="link">Title</option>
<option  value="link">Title</option>
<option  value="link">Title</option>
<option  value="link">Title</option>
<option  value="link">Title</option>


</select>
```

I tried with

```
window.addEvent('domready', function () {



      $$('ul.nav li').each(function(el) {

            var option = new Element('option',{html:el.get('html')});
            option.replaces(el);
        });
      $$('ul.nav').each(function(el) {

            var select= new Element('select',{html:el.get('html')});
            select.replaces(el);
        });
});
```

but as you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/xVrZe/ I get all li values without href attributes and my sub ul li's are in 1 select option.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function() {
    var Options = new Elements(),
        ul = document.getElement('ul.nav');

    ul.getElements('li a').each(function(el) {
        Options.include(new Element('option', {
            text: el.get('html'),
            value: el.get('href')
        }));
    });

    new Element('select', {
        events: {
            change: function() {
                window.location.href = this.get('value');
            }
        }
    }).adopt(Options).replaces(ul);
}());
```

this will convert and remove the original ul, also - attach a change event. http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/xVrZe/2/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function () {     
  $$('ul.nav').each(function(el) {
    var options = el.getElements('li > a').map(function(el) {
        return new Element('option',{html:el.get('html'), value:el:get('href')});
    });

    var select= new Element('select');
    select.adopt(options);
    select.replaces(el);
  });
});
```

The problems were:

1) you need to start with each nav and concern yourself only with its content (in case you have more than one nav on the page)

2) you need to get the 'a' tags, not 'li' tags

Comment: thank you much this has helped to get me in the right direction. problem I had is that my a's also had spans inside with some text that I had to eliminate.

Comment: Ah, in that case, you can use get('text') instead of get('html'). Basically, tags will be stripped automatically.